# How to calculate load bearing capacity of a floating pavement?

Tags: concrete, pavement

Given tire load of a vehicle, how do I calculate load bearing capacity of a non-reinforced concrete pavement floating on a layer of heat insulation material, which is on the RC base? I can't figure out how to use (or if I can use) soil mechanics models because I don't have any information on cohesion etc. I just have nominal carrying capacity of insulation foam (200kPA) and how much it collapses at a given load. (We want to use the roof as a garage, which was not designed as a garage.)